# Scalling the items in items Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am developing a control (Items control) to show boxes in a Room(for example sack).
If the room size is 10 *10 feet then I have to scale it to fit my Screen.
Also all the objects in the room will also need to be scaled.

In my view model I have a collection of these objects(i.e. boxes) with actual dimension.

The ItemPanel of my items control is like a canvas where I can freely move the objects.

currently in my Measure Override or Arrange override of the itemsPanel I get the height and width of the panel. With that height and width I apply the scaling to object while arranging.

So my question is, is the approach better or there is a better alternative.

Regards
Saurabh Dighade

Comment: I believe you are on a right path.

Comment: may be you can try to use ScrollViewer and set his size. And ScrollViewer will scale all elements that are inside

Comment: @Sasha, thanks for looking but don't think scrollViewer can Scale.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code

```
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_1" Margin="10" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}">
    <StackPanel x:Uid="StackPanel_1" Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal"> 
        <Slider x:Uid="ScaleSlider" x:Name="ScaleSlider" Minimum="0.2" Maximum="5" LargeChange="0.05" SmallChange="0.01" 
                Value="{Binding ScaleSlider}" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="0.1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer x:Uid="ScrollViewer_1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Border x:Uid="AlStatusBorder" BorderBrush="#101010" BorderThickness="3"
         Background="{Binding Color}"
         x:Name="AlStatusBorder"
         Padding="5"
         CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid x:Uid="Grid_2">  
            <!-- Tachometer Gauge -->
                <gauge:CircularGauge x:Uid="gauge:CircularGauge_1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FrameType="CircularTopGradient" Width="150" Height="150" Radius="75" Background="#444444"
                        RimBrush="#444444">
                    <gauge:CircularGauge.LayoutTransform >
                        <ScaleTransform x:Uid="ScaleTransform_1" ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider, Path=Value}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider, Path=Value}"/>
                    </gauge:CircularGauge.LayoutTransform>  
                </gauge:CircularGauge>             
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

In grid_2 I implement my userControl. When I change a property ScaleSlider, element becomes bigger or smaller, and my usercontrol that is inside also changes it's sizes. May be it is what you are looking for. At least I can move this userControl; change sizes only by changing one property. Note that Im binding ScaleX and ScaleY values

Comment: Hi, I do have the scale and I cannot use scaleTransform. My Main concern is where should I apply the scale. i.e. Scaling is not a  issue where to apply it, is. But thanks for looking and response

Comment: Do you use it like <yourXamlElement.LayoutTransform><ScaleTransform/></yourXamlElement.LayoutTransform>?

Comment: No I don't use any LayoutTransform, I actually Scale the item. for example in the room is Size(100,100) and if my scale is 0.1 then my Scaled Size is Size(10,10). The scale calculation logic is separate the problem is should we scale everything in View Model or should we scale it in customePanel for my itemsControl.

Comment: @SD13 try to scale custom panel. in view model you should change only properties, to change view. I mean you change in your model, for example width, and this via binding changes your view's width.